# How to get iterator number in all() function for which the condition is not met?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible? For example, for a column in the form:

```
     Col
 0   aaa
 1   bb
 2   ccc
 3   ddd
```

and for the condition:

```
all(df['Col'].str.len()<3)
```

get the iterator/index number = 1

Comment: `all` returns a boolean. It can't return anything else. Why are you using it?

Comment: Do you with to get iterator of all of the values from the original list that satisfy a certain condition ?

Comment: because at some stage it was the most optimal solution, and I only needed the Bulowska value, and only now it turned out that I need to elaborate on it and get more details :)

Comment: that not satisfy a certain condition :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df['Col'][df['Col'].str.len()<3]
```

to get all rows that satisfy the condition, or

```py
(df['Col'].str.len()<3).idxmax()
```

to get only the index of the first matching row.